# Unable to cast reflection called method type IEnumerable<Tuple>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I have an error when I call a method in reflection, I can't cast the result to its base Type `(IEnumerable<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression>>)` which seems strange.

I don't have this problem when I cast another method in Expression. I guess it's the IEnumerable or the Tuple that is the problem. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Error when I call the first method below:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression>> ConvertOrderByToTupleExpression(Type entityType, string orderBy)
{
    return (IEnumerable<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression>>)typeof(RepositoryReflectionHelper)
                .GetMethods()
                .First(x => x.Name == nameof(RepositoryReflectionHelper.ConvertOrderByToTupleExpression) && x.IsGenericMethod && x.GetParameters().Count() == 1)
                .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { entityType })
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { orderBy });
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>> ConvertOrderByToTupleExpression<TEntity>(string orderBy)
{
    List<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>> orderByCriteriaTuple = new List<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>>();

    return orderByCriteriaTuple;
}
```

UPDATE:

Same Errors for "reverse" actions in the below code:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression>> orderByExpression = RepositoryReflectionHelper.ConvertOrderByToTupleExpression(entityType, orderBy);

var calledFunction = GetManyPaging(orderByExpression);

public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetManyPaging(IEnumerable<System.Tuple<SortingOrder, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>> orderByCriteriaTuple)
{
    // Do something not significant
}
```

Thank for your times

Comment: C# does not support [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) for classes.

Comment: oh ok :/ So I'm constrained to use `dynamic` type right ?

Comment: No, actually you are not, but you will need to remap tuple elements manually. At least it is the only way I can think of (at least without more reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support [variance for classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) but you can leverage the fact that it supports variance for interfaces, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant interface and `Tuple<T1, T2>` implements [`ITuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=net-6.0):

```cs
object tuple = new[]
{
    new Tuple<int, Expression<Func<int>>>(1, () => 1)
};

IEnumerable<Tuple<int, Expression>> enumerable = ((IEnumerable<ITuple>)tuple)
    .Select(t => Tuple.Create((int)t[0], (Expression) t[1]))
    .ToList(); // to list to make sure it does work
```

Comment: Yes I would not miss it, I have only one point left. I have the same error in reverse when I try to pass Tuple<Expression> to a function which need `Tuple<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>` as parameter :/ 
am I forced to expand the type in the function parameter?

Comment: @Mulaga you need either to expand the function parameter or "reassemble" your tuple again. TBH without more complete view of what, how and why you are trying to do its hard to give any concrete advices how to do things better.

Comment: Ok, I will update the question for this reverse errors, and if you don't provide others advices than expand the function parameter i will close the subject ! thank again.